# why is my ternary boolean operator showing the opposite

Tags: java, boolean, return, operator-keyword, ternary

isnt the ternary operator suppose to work as  arg ? true:false ??? so if duration and petroleum are more than the stated amount than field variables, it should return true.. but this returns false instead

```
public class test12 {
    int duration = 260;
    int petroleum = 300;
    boolean result;

    public void checktrain(){
        boolean result = duration>=250 && petroleum>=235? true : false;
        this.result = result;
    }

    public void run(){
        System.out.print(result);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        test12 tr = new test12();
        tr.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need for the ternary operator at all. You can just do `boolean result = duration >= 250 && petroleum >= 235`.

Answer (score 5):

Result is `false` because you have never called the method `checktrain` and default value of member variable result is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to call `checktrain()`.So as it remains with default value `false` of boolean.

Try to call that method.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
test12 tr = new test12();
tr.checktrian();
tr.run();
}
```

And check train method can be written simply as

```
public void checktrain(){
this.result= duration>=250 && petroleum>=235;
}
```

And even you can avoid that boolean by writing

```
  public boolean checktrain(){
    return  duration>=250 && petroleum>=235;
    }
```